# Pointer to struct ,is this even a pointer to struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-address

I have a struct and it has variables in it.
Now I need to allocate memory dynamically, so initially I use

```
Struct struct-name *a =Null;
```

Latter on , I *will allocate memory to it* using `malloc` ,then I use

```
a[0].variableA=allocate , a[0].variableB=allocate.
```

My question is , is this even a pointer to struct, because no where I give the address of struct . And moreover this technique works , how does it know the address of struct . When I'm not explicitly giving address of struct using '&'. I know this might be silly but I got confused .Thanks .

```
Struct st
{
 int a ;
int b;
}
Struct a *ptr=NULL;
```

In main

```
    ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct st)*2);
    //Assume array of size 2 is created 
Now I can use 
    ptr[0].a=10;
```

How can I use even without explicitly giving address of struct to it.

Comment: They say that an image says more than a thousand words. Well actual code beats that by saying more than a thousand images. So instead of describing your code, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and *show* it to us. And if you haven't done it yet, then please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: My edit changed the question for sure.

Comment: Well I got the question ..check the answer.

Comment: So you wonder why the compiler doesn't complain that you dereference a null or otherwise invalid pointer? That's how the language is designed. C gives you enough rope to do whatever you want, if you then chose to tie it into a noose and hang yourself that's your problem and not the fault of C or any compiler. Don't do stupid stuff, or bad things will happen.

Comment: ***Or*** are you wondering why you don't need to allocate memory for the members of the structure? Well that's because those are part of the structure itself, and are counted when you do `sizeof` on the structure, and allocated as part of the structure with the `malloc` call.

Comment: __array notation__ is __equivalent__ to __pointer notation__. That is, `ptr[1].a=10` is equivalent to `*((ptr+1)+offset(a))=10` (with `offset` a hypothetical notation indicating the offset of member a in the struct, which is zero here).

Comment: I believe in doing  stupid things while I learn. Thanks . :) @Some programmer dude

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude.: OP didn't clear the question first. Your insightful comments are really helpful. And I hope OP next time will put in the first edit the whole question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you are not getting how `malloc` works. (You mentioned *I will allocate memory to it using malloc*)

```
struct struct_name *a = NULL;
a = malloc(sizeof *a);
...
```

This computes the number of bytes that a `struct struct_name` occupy in memory, then requests that many bytes from `malloc`
and assigns the result (i.e., the *starting address of the memory chunk* that was just created using `malloc`) to a
pointer named `a`. That is the whole story.

Now you will access it after making it sure that it didn't return `NULL`. No need to apply `&` address of to any `struct struct_name` variable instance.

In your case, `ptr` is used to access the different struct instance allocated dynamically - where is the address? The address pointing to the first instance is contained in `ptr`. Then you used `ptr[0]` or `ptr[1]` to get to that structure instance. And then you accessed it.

> And yes `ptr` is a pointer to struct.

One extra thing:-

`malloc` may not be able to service the request, it may return a null pointer. It is good to
check for this to prevent later attempts to dereference the null pointer. If you dereference a NULL pointer then it's undefined behavior.